# Magic Font Sizing From Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8.1

I started creating an app using Bootstrap, and ended up customizing the CSS so much as to not need Bootstrap at all. However, when removing the bootstrap CSS file, I ran into a problem.

I have an element which I am assigning 120% `font-size`:

```
#page-title {
    font-size:120%;
}
```

Now with Bootstrap 3.3.5, the font is one size, apparently calculated to 14px according to chrome dev tools.

However, if I remove the Bootstrap CSS and just set `body` to have a `font-size` of 14px (and the various other Bootstrap styles such as `line-height`), the font is a different size, but only on Windows Phone 8.1 IE11.

my `body` css is the following:

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

Which is, as far as I can tell, the same as Bootstrap's. I am also still including all the same `meta` tags. The only difference is the CSS file.

My question is not why does this specific version of IE do this (as I cannot recreate it on Windows 8.1 IE11), but what magic does Bootstrap's CSS have that I can copy?

Comment: normalize.css might help http://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize

Comment: @TinyGiant Hadn't thought of that, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went digging through the entirety of the Bootstrap CSS and found the bit that was missing.

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
```

This fixes the font sizing (and a few other tweaks) On Windows Phones and Tablets that appear correctly with Bootstrap, but not without.